# use jquery to select a dropdown option on button click control

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have tried this code.

```
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#MyButton').click(function () {
    $('#DropDownList2').val("3");;
  });
</script>



<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">SELECT</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">23</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">32</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">44</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">61</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="MAX" />
```

but it is not seam to be working. i don't know if i used the correct version of jquery file.
please check
if there is any alternative with or without using jquery
thank you

Comment: Your caps button seems broken...

Comment: Duplicate question asked by OP. @user3651976 You should engaged answerer about what didn't worked in your other question

Comment: Please ask your question precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Server side gets **different** ID :

Do this instead :

`$('#<%= MyButton.ClientID%>').click(function () {...`

Also move this to here : ( you can't register a future element( unless use `.on`) or document.ready

[image]

Comment: OP has ClientIDMode="Static" which cause same ClientID as Server side id

Comment: @Adil not on the button ! which is why it's not working which is why I dont understand how it's duplicate.